# inline editing - how do you guys do this on the front-end?

Tags: inline-editing

I am applying a inline editing method that involves colorbox and the backend. below every entry there's a link that opens up an inline popup with the correspondent "edit entry" screen from the backend. it's very usable, and needs almost no additional programming.

but since we have safecracker there must be more evolved methods to do this? 
like "edit in place". anybody care to share?

cheers
stefan

Answer (score 1):

I use Safecracker to edit webpages on the frontend all the time. I find it useful to keep some editors away from the control panel, especially when all they need do is change some text or add an image. Safecracker File is OK for images. I've had problems adding images within text box areas, it depends on which file browser being used. You can do a lot of what can be done via backend CP but not everything.

I tend to open up a new page template with the Safecracker fields and pass the entry_id via a segment_X.

It can also be done using modal boxes to give a more inline feel, as you're already doing with backend, but can get tricky refreshing parent page to show the edits made, Javascript or Ajax should help here.

Answer (score 1):

We've done the same as Samsull for custom applications built with ExpressionEngine, where we had a dashboard of information stored in entries, and "edit" links alongside content to edit that information.

We passed those edit URLs to a jQuery lightbox that would load a Safecracker form. You'll probably need to re-output some of the core entry fields, like URL Title, in hidden form fields, but you can limit the visible Safecracker form to just the content field you want the user to edit.

We would set the return URL of the Safecracker form to a particular page URL that just had some JavaScript in it. That JavaScript would close the lightbox and refresh the parent page, which would then display the updated content.